# $A \subset B$ if and only if $B^c ⊂ A^c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A \subset B$ if and only if $B^c ⊂ A^c$, where $A^c$ and $B^c$ denotes the compliment of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

I'm trying to prove that if this is true,to prove it using mathematics. Else, If it is is false, disprove it by counter-example.

So if we can assume that(as an example) $A = \{a,b,c \}$ and $B=\{a,b,c,d,e  \}$. How could I go about this?

I know that $A\subset B$ would be true since $A$ is a strict subset of $B$. But is it true iff $B^c ⊂ A^c$ , how could I word this?

Comment: "So if we can assume that(as an example) A={a,b,c} and B={a,b,c,d,e}. How could I go about this?"  Uh, you can't. You can't ever prove something by an example.  You can only disprove by counterexample.  But as this is true you can't prove it with an example.

Comment: "A={a,b,c} and B={a,b,c,d,e}"  Wha't your universal set?  If it's letters of the alphabet the $B^c=\{f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,\}$ and $A^c=\{d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\}$.  And indeed in this case $B^c\subset A^c$.... Which proves absolutely nothing as that is just one example.

Comment: What happens if I have something such as this?

Consider my universal set to be {0,1}

A={0}, B={0,1}. A' would be {1} but B' would be an empty set, therefore proving this statement false, or would an example such as this not work? Sorry for all the questions, it is a topic we learned today and is on the practice problems.

Comment: $B' = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subset \{1\}=A^c$ so it is still true.  The empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: Great, I think I have a way to write my answer now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In your example, suppose the universe is $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$.  What is $B'?$  What is $A'?$  Is $B' \subset A'?$  You are given that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.  So if an element is not in $B$, can it be in $A$?

Comment: B' would be {f} and A' would be {d,e,f} , so B'⊂A' is true since {f} is a strict subset of {d,e,f}. So would that make the statement true? Or am I looking at the question wrong still.

Comment: That would make it true for that $A$ and that $B$ and that choice of universe.  Now you just have to show it is true for every *other* possible set and every other possible universal set.   How much time do you have to list them all?

Comment: The question says if it's true to prove it mathematically, and that's it. So it looks like I might be writing for a looooooooong time :p

Comment: @snuffleupagus:  The way to do it in general is to say $A \subset B$ means $\forall a (a \in A \implies a \in B)$ and it appears you are using strict subsets so it also means $\exists b (b \not \in A \wedge b \in B)$.  You want to use those to show $\forall c (c \in B' \implies c \in A')$, which looks like the contrapositive of the above and the corresponding thing about the one element difference.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in B^c$ then $x \not \in B$.

So is it possible that $x \in A$ if $A \subset B$?

.....

Just do this by definitions.

$A \subset B$ if and only if every elements of $A$ is also an element of $B$. Which is true if and only if none of the elements of $A$ are in $B$.  Which is true if and only if all of the elements that aren't in $B$ are not in $A$.  And so.....